# thin the influx of migrants

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't quite understand the phrase "thin the influx of migrants" - "Thin" means "make the number of imgrants less", so "thin the influx of migrants" would mostly mean "make the number of migrants less" and a basic means to do so is to enhance the border to prevent migrants from crossing. I am not sure it is what the phrase means.

Why this question?  The reason is that a flow of imigrants is formed in a foreign country before crossing the border. So you cannot control the size of the flow. So "thinning the influx" can only refer to the control of the border crossing to thwart the influx. Here's the catch: I understood that the money would be used in humanitarian aid (helping the imigrants), now it seems to mean using force to block their ways to seek help (they are refugees).

> Since Bosnia became a route for thousands of people hoping to reach Europe in 2018, the European Union has provided 89 million euros, or more than $108 million, to the country’s authorities or organizations working there as part of a larger strategy to **thin the influx of migrants** at its external borders. (Bosnia isn’t part of the European Union, but it borders Croatia, which is.)

> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/14/world/europe/bosnia-migrants.html?smid=tw-nytimes&smtyp=cur)

Comment: Google Dictionary: thin verb
1.
make or become less dense, crowded, or numerous.
"the remorseless fire of archers thinned their ranks"
Similar:
become less dense/numerous
decrease, diminish, dwindle

Comment: I think it means that the humanitarian aid would be provided in Bosnia, so the refugees would be more comfortable there and less likely to try to enter Croatia.  This **thins the influx** of migrants into the EU.